# Command failed with exit code 2 in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I HAVE THIS ERROR

On build app in ionic

```
sudo ionic build android
```

> Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH.
>   You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
>
> ```
> at /home/sbh/testt/mobilebra/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:206:19
> at _fulfilled (/home/sbh/testt/mobilebra/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
> at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/sbh/testt/mobilebra/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
> at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/sbh/testt/mobilebra/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
> at /home/sbh/testt/mobilebra/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
> at flush (/home/sbh/testt/mobilebra/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
> at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
> at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
> at run (bootstrap_node.js:422:7)
> ```
>
> Error: /home/sbh/testt/mobilebra/platforms/android/cordova/build:
>   Command failed with exit code 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

(nano is my preference, use whatever your heart desires)

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

add the following lines, modifying the paths if your SDKs in a different spot:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```